# username and password fields are not working correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication, post

I am trying to make a simple login page where if the username and the password are both equal to "admin" then i want to redirect to another page called "admin_page.php". I have the following code but for some reason the login works for whatever i input on username and password fields, even if there are empty.
Can anyone tell me why is thats happening? 
Here is my code:

```
<body>

<?php


 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['psw'];
  if (($user === "admin") && ($pass ==="admin")) {
           header("Location: admin_page.php");

  } else {
  echo("error ! please enter correct data");
}

  echo $user;

}

?>

<div class="bg">

    <div class="a">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
      <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="psw">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});


Route::post('/', function () {
    return view('admin');
});

Route::post('/', function () {
    return view('admin_page');
});
// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::view('/home', "home"); // for controller
// Route::view('/welcome', "welcome"); // for controller

Route::view('/admin', "admin"); // for controller
Route::view('/admin_page', "admin_page"); // for controller
```

index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Just a random aside, you don't need `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on your form tag unless you are using it to upload files.

Comment: Anyway, taken by itself that code should work and only redirect you if the credentials match. Have you done any debugging to check what values are actually being received in $_POST, and what path the code is actually taking? It's unclear what the relevant of web.php is to this btw. Are you using some sort of framework as well? If so then it probably already provides built-in mechanisms for authentication, and for correctly redirecting to views.

Comment: @ADyson even if i remove the header(location..) and press the login im still accessing the admin_page.php !! and i dont know why is that happening

Comment: what does `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` resolve to, if you look at your rendered HTML (in your browser's View Source)? It almost sounds like the form is posting back to admin_page.php directly...

Comment: Or it could be that `Route::post('/', function () {
    return view('admin_page');
});` is coming into play, if PHP_SELF is just the root of the website. Like I said, if you're using an MVC framework which involves views, routes and controllers, then you almost certainly shouldn't be writing your own login code, or your own redirection code. It almost certainly has these features built in already. So the quickest way to make your code work properly is probably to use those features as intended.

Comment: @ADyson  <form method="post" action="/DTask/index.php" > !  i will update the question to show what index.php is, i dont know why is rendering to there, it was there where i created the project

Comment: still have access to the admin_page.php with wrong or empty credentials

Comment: its becuase where your checking your request params.  They should be done before your return the view.  What route does this view belong to admin?

Comment: Ok so now it's clearer you're using Laravel. So again, as I said before, stop trying to make your own login page. Use the ready-made functionality. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart . Your attempt right now is screwing up at least partly because you're not sticking to the MVC framework properly, and trying to do other kinds of redirection. It's just not how it's meant to work in that kind of framework. use the tools the framework provides you.

Comment: I've added the Laravel tag to the question, so maybe people with specific expertise in that framework can give you more detailed advice.

Comment: @ADyson no it was me who added the Laravel tag, :))  you have overwritten it...

Comment: @MaxMuster actually I [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26118441) your edit, which wasn't fully approved yet, and altered it to remove some unnecessary tags, and add back in the HTML one which is still relevant :-) . So yes you got there first, but your change wasn't visible to anyone until I'd reviewed and improved it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you are checking for your request parameters.

Your View

```
<body>



<div class="bg">
     @if(count($errors) > 0)
         @foreach($errors as $error)
             <p>{{$error}}</p>
         @endforeach
     @endif
    <div class="a">
    <form method="post" action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="psw">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Your routes

```
 Route::post('/', function (Request $request) {
   $errors = [];
   if($request->has('username') && $request->has('psw')){
        if($request->input('username') === 'admin' && $request->input('psw') === 'admin'){
          return redirect('/admin_page');
        }

        else{$errors[] = "Invalid login attempt";}

   }


   return view('admin', ['errors' => $errors]);
});
```

But this is not the way to do it this just solves your current problem.  I would advise on looking into using laravel's built in authentication.

Comment: why i got the following error on the line "return view('admin');" 
ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) ?

Comment: i had a typo was missing the if end bracket.  I added it in

Comment: okay so also there i will check if the username and password is equal with admin?

Comment: I updated my answer to check the input and return errors.

Comment: i dont understand why the login still working with any input. thank you for the answer any really helped me to understand the concept